# Can SDEMON command be used on ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase

Working on ArcSDE I need to use SDEMON to monitor or stop users, so that I can do my updates.

Can SDEMON command be used on ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop?

Comment: Clarification please:  Are you asking if a) The `sdemon` utility can be used to terminate a Desktop session, b) The `sdemon` utility can be used to terminate a Direct Connect connection *from* within Desktop, c) The `sdemon` utility can be invoked from Desktop, d) if Desktop has a logical equivalent to `sdemon -o kill`, or e) Something else?  Please edit the question.

Comment: Sorry, Let me clear the confusion. I am connecting to SDE on oracle from my desktop. Everything works better, but to update certain datasets, They need be locked off the SDE. In which case I learnt that SDEMON help to monitor the users and connections. I never used this command so asked if SDEMON is used from server only or we can give this command from Desktop as well. Hope that clears.

Comment: This is a key point:  The technology ArcSDE is connected *though*, not *to*.  You connect *to* Oracle *using* ArcSDE.  The `sdemon` utility is deprecated at 10.2, and unavailable at 10.3.  If you've never used it, you have no call to start doing so now. http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2013/10/04/do-this-not-that-alternatives-to-using-sde-command-line-tools/  Please edit the question, lest it be closed for being unclear.

Comment: For PostgreSQL you can determine (and boot off) connected users with PGAdmin, there is likely to be a similar utility for Oracle (but don't count on it being free). One thing you must know is that despite killing a connection it will pop back up again almost immediately (kinda like nailing jelly to a tree). The purpose for the -o kill was to release connections from crashed sessions only. To get users out for the purposes of update your best tool is eMail (and ask nicely).

Comment: e-mail and stopping ArcGIS Server services

Comment: According to http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00290000004z000000 you need SDEmon to stop the service and then http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcsde-application-server-microsoft-sql-server/10.2/index.html#//009500000023000000 SDEmon to start it again. I assume something else will replace it in 10.3. Oracle has only one database so you should be able to stop/start the service in Services; RDBMS that support many databases (may) need each one stopped individually which could be a pain. Note, this only applies to services, not direct connections.

Comment: You don't need the ArcSDE application server service to use  ArcGIS Server services.  In fact, it's best if you don't install the application server at all.  Nothing replaces the application server at 10.3 -- it's just gone.